# Powershell Windows Service password script not executing

Tags: powershell, server, passwords, windows-services, wmi

Below I have a powershell script that attempts to change a windows service password on a remote under a lofin account with a partial match. So if the log on as account name is set as **username1** all i need is to filter it by **username** and attempts to change that service account since it is a partial match.

The problem? Well, it does not change the password at all. However, restarting/stopping the windows service works, but it seems not to change the password. Could you please show me what is going wrong?

```
$partialUsername = "log_on_account"

$newPassword = "NewPassword123!"

$serverName = 'computername'

$scriptTest = {
    param($partialUsername, $newPassword)

    $services = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service

    $services | Where-Object { $_.StartName -like "*$partialUsername*" } | ForEach-Object {
        $serviceName = $_.Name
        Write-Host "Processing service: $serviceName"

        Write-Host "Stopping $serviceName..."
        Stop-Service -Name $serviceName

        $serviceConfig = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='$serviceName'"
        $serviceConfig.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $newPassword)

        Write-Host "Starting $serviceName..."
        Start-Service -Name $serviceName

        Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
        $serviceStatus = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
        if ($serviceStatus.Status -eq "Running") {
            Write-Host "$serviceName restarted successfully."
        } else {
            Write-Host "$serviceName failed to restart."
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Command -Credential domain\username -ComputerName $serverName -ScriptBlock $scriptTest -ArgumentList $partialUsername, $newPassword`
```

Comment: Change `$serviceConfig.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $newPassword)` to `$serviceConfig.Change($null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $null, $_.StartName, $newPassword, $null, $null, $null)`